# Rendering templates based on session variable

Tags: backbone.js, meteor, handlebars.js

I am using Meteor, Handlebars, and Backbone to create a multipage application. I have a Router set up using backbone which sets a session variable, `currentPage`. How can I render a different template depending on the value of `currentPage`?

I was told that I could create a Template helper function that would do this, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if currentPage is global and pages are stored as strings, then I would expect this to work:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('currentPageIs',function(page){
    return currentPage == page;
});

// and in the html:
{{#if currentPageIs '/posts'}}
    {{> posts}}
{{else}}
    {{> homepage}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution is here: https://gist.github.com/3221138

But I would strongly recommend installing [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router). This will require you to first install [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite).

Also, know that an official routing solution is on the [roadmap](https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm).

Answer (score 0):

The best choice would to use Iron-Router, but it you don't want that here is a nice pattern to change the template:

```
//HTML
<body>
  {{>mainTemplate}}
</body>

//JS Client Initially
var current = Template.initialTemplate;
var currentDep = new Deps.Dependency;

Template.mainTemplate = function()
{
  currentDep.depend();
  return current;
};

function setTemplate( newTemplate )
{
    current = newTemplate;
    currentDep.changed();
};

//Later
setTemplate( Template.someOtherTemplate );
```

I don't know how to check for the route but if you can, then you can just use the proposed `setTemplate` function to change the template conditionally.

Comment: I tried this in Meteor 0.9.4 but it's giving the error:
Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: No such template: mainTemplate